# How to set callback host (not path) for .NET Core Open ID Connect?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, identityserver4, openid, okta

In .NET Core, using Open ID Connect, I'm trying to debug locally behind a local Nginx instance.

Nginx and hosts file settings are used so that a custom domain e.g. `https://example.com` is used to access the web app running locally, rather than the usual `https://localhost:<port>`

The issue I have, is that the identifty provider, Okta, always calls back to `https://localhost:<port>/authorization-code/callback` rather than `https://example.com/authorization-code/callback`. Both `https://localhost:<port>` and `https://example.com` are included in allowed callback URIs in Okta.

The .NET Open ID Connect library appears to discover the callback host automatically and I can't find a setting to change it, only the path.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
    options.Authority = Configuration["Okta:Issuer"];
    options.CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
...

Is there a setting I can use to forward the host for the callback?
```

Comment: I can't make much sense of your comment. Regarding why behind nginx - to replicate deployed environment as closely as possible.

Comment: I was curios why you _run the browser to perform the interactive signin_ behind the nginx. really unusual approach. if you take the browser outside you should have no problem at all

Comment: Thanks for trying but I don't think you can help here. I'll leave the question open.

Comment: just tried to point you where to look at. you question is not specifically about okta nor Identityserver. it's about MVC, relative paths composition and OIdC middleware, using it as a base. the short answer would be: you can't. you can't define an absolute path as the middleware needs to register a handler, and it can do that only within the app. what you can do is to play with `PathBase`. when set, it will be cut from CallbackPath when registering the handler. but totally replacing the domain... I'm pretty sure is a wrong way